# SPI and clock active low or high

Tags: spi

I am trying to get SPI working on an MCU. The SCK on the MCU is labelled \$\overline{SCK}\$ which means it active low but my device has no overline on the SCK. Can I use the same clock. If not what can I do?

Comment: Can you provide Datasheet or Name of your MCU?

Comment: SCK generally will have programmable polarity based on CPOL bits.check this:https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CDAQygQwAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FSerial_Peripheral_Interface_Bus%23Clock_polarity_and_phase&ei=EnleUoSeFpHrrQf23YDwBA&usg=AFQjCNF2gf_GVuGEbHnvJZDqr1UyOeDRBg&sig2=JDDtj6riU0i5z7jK-wR2hw&bvm=bv.54176721,d.bmk

Comment: There is no standard in the SPI world for "clock polarity" or "clock phase". The SPI controllers on most modern MCUs have configuration bits for these parameters that allow them to be used with pretty much any peripheral device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clocks don't generally have an active "level" per say; in many cases clock outputs will specify that they'll only stop when they're at a certain level, but otherwise clocks have active *edges*.  Typically, SPI devices will use one clock edge as a signal to output each bit of data, and the following clock edge as a signal that to latch the data from the other device.  In some cases, SPI devices will asynchronously place the first bit of data; the first clock transition will latch that and the second will output the second bit, the third will latch the second bit and the fourth will place the next, etc.  The fifteenth transition will latch the last bit, and the sixteenth will indicate that the device should start outputting the first bit of the next byte sometime before the next clock transition.

Answer (score 0):

1) Are you sure it's SCK and not SS or CS (Slave Select / Chip Select). It is uncommon for the clock symbol to be negated.

2) If it is SCK, you might want to know that there are actually 4 SPI modes which are decided upon by the parameters CPOL and CPHA. Wikipedia explains the differences in detail. Usually a slave will support one (or more) modes and the master (your CPU) needs to be configured accordingly. Most microcontrollers I know can be configured for one of the four SPI Modes.